# MYSQL Simple IF statement based on CURRENT_TIME

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'd like to run an SQL statement, to return the price of a product, but if the current_time is within start / end date, return promo price.

```
| id  |  price  |  promo_price  | promo_start | promo_end  |
+-----+---------+---------------+-------------+------------+
|  1  |   5     |      4        | 1375709473  | 1375709473 |
```

SQL to return JUST product price, regardless of promo:

```
SELECT p.`price` 
FROM products p 
WHERE p.`id` = 1
```

How would I create this as an SQL-IF statement?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    IF(unix_timestamp() BETWEEN p.promo_start AND p.promo_end, p.promo_price, p.price) as real_price
FROM products p 
WHERE p.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(p.`promo_start` <= unix_timestamp() AND p.`promo_end` >= unix_timestamp(), p.`promo_price`,p.`price`) as price
FROM products p 
WHERE p.`id` = 1
```

Use above query.

OR you can use CASE:

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN p.`promo_start` <= unix_timestamp() AND p.`promo_end` >= unix_timestamp() 
         THEN p.`promo_price` 
         ELSE p.`price` END 
   FROM products p 
      WHERE p.`id` = 1;
```

[Tutorials](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html) is here.

Comment: Great, now I understand the syntax, however using BETWEEN (@vatev solution) seems more logical. Big thanks to both.

Comment: @BigDistance I am going to add the tutorial link also. you can learn more from there.

Comment: @BigDistance If you feel that this answer is good then do not forgot to mark it as accepted. many thanks.